# 2D Char array diagonal push back from a certain index?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, vector, char

I need to create a function that takes a 2d char matrix and a string as a parameter, and the thing is, I need to push back all diagonal char collection which are the same characters as the string parameter, and the same length with the string parameter, for example if the matrix is:

```
S L A R O Q M S K
L T M A K I T T E
P O A L K Q H M C
K L A C O P L I K
W R Y U K S A X Z
P Q K I O O H J L
```

and the string parameter is "STACK", I need to pushback "{S, T, A, C, K}" in a 1d temporary char vector as you can see on the very first left top - bottom right diagonal.

So far I created something like this:

```
string matrixToString(vector<vector<char>> & mat, string searchWord) {
string s = "";
vector<char> temp;
char ch = searchWord[0];
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < mat.size(); i++) {
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < mat[0].size(); j++) {
        for (unsigned int m = ch, n = ch; m < searchWord.length() && n < searchWord.length(); i++, j++) {
            temp.push_back(mat[m][n]);
        }
    }
}
s = charToString(temp);

return s;
```

}

Sample Input is:

```
SEARCH
DAPIJY
QTVAMK
NRAELQ
LGIFTZ
///
SAVE
```

nothing being pushed in my vector, but expected was:
{S, A, V, E}

what is wrong with this code and how can I implement such a function? Thank you for your help.

Comment: why do *you* think there is somethign wrong? Please include example input, output and expected output in the question

Comment: So, you have to return the `string` (is it a `std::string`? If not, why?) `searchWord` if it's present in the 2D table, diagonally. Is it correct? Do you mind explaining what `char ch = searchWord[0];` and later `unsigned int m = ch`, `temp.push_back(mat[m][n]);` are supposed to do?

Comment: @Bob__ Yes, it is correct. Actually, in the first place I thought that if I be sure that the first char is the same, then I can search for the string, that's why I tried searchWord[0] thing. For the rest, I don't know they are just my garbage trials.

Comment: @Bob__ and also, we supposed to use namespace standards in our assignments, that's why.

Comment: In `unsigned int m = ch`, you assign a character code to a counter... not the thing intended, I think

Comment: Also you increase `i` and `j` in the inner loop, that would wreak havoc on the outer loops, would inner loop run actually (it doesn’t as `m` starts well above word length)

Comment: Let's say `ch` is equal to `'S'`, what would `mat['S']['S']` lead to? Check the values of `n` and `m` using a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

A wrong thing is `unsigned int m = ch, n = ch`. `ch` is not a position in the source string but rather, a character [code], so assigning it to a counter is meaningless.

Another problem (more like a typo) is incrementing `i` and `j` in the inner loop (and not touching `m` and `n` at all so the loop would be infinite, wouldn’t `m` be so large initially).

One possible implementation of that inner loop would actually iterate over `searchWord` and compare its (k)th character to (i+k,j+k)th character of the matrix (be careful with matrix bounds, though). Only if all of the comparisons succeed you need to record the string, or maybe return it immediately (unless you need to e.g. return the location, you can return `searchWord` here as you just checked that it is equal to what you need to return).

Comment: `string matrixToString(vector<vector<char>> & mat, string searchWord) {
    string s = "";
    vector<char> temp;
    char ch = searchWord[0];
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < mat.size(); i++) {
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < mat[0].size()+1; j++) {
                if (mat[i][j] == ch) {
                    for (unsigned int m = 0; m < searchWord.length(); m++) {
                        temp.push_back(mat[i+m][j+m]);

`
I made something like this but gives bad access.

Comment: It does. Be careful with matrix bounds. E.g. `i+m` is definitely out of bounds when both `i` and `m` are large.